# Level Curves of a Radial Basis Function (RBF)

Tags: calculus, probability, multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry

I have a radial basis function (RBF) from sampled data points from a function. The RBF looks like,

$$
h(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} w_i \exp(-\gamma ||x-m_i||^2)
$$

where $\gamma,w_i$ are the result of RBF interpolation, and $m_1,..,m_N$ are the selected basis points.

My question is how can I retrieve the $x$ values that belong to a level set $h(x)=c$, or a contour at $c$ for this RBF function? What methods would be necessary? Root finding (multivariate)? Or turning the RBF function into a probability distribution and sample from it? In essence I need the $x$ values that will make this equation true,

$$
w_1 \exp(-\gamma ||x-m_1||^2) + ... + w_n \exp(-\gamma ||x-m_N||^2) = c
$$

where $c$ is a scalar constant, like 0, 1, or 2, .. etc. If RBF form is too complex a cubic based RBF would be fine too,

$$
w_1 ||x-m_1||^3 + ... + w_n ||x-m_N||^3 = c
$$

Is there a clean analytical way to retrieve this result?

My ultimate goal is to calculate the area within this contour, so maybe there are more shortcuts available in that case.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: You may first want to check if $\gamma$ and $c$ are large and the $m_i$ are far enough apart. This is the case of well separated peaks and so you can just ask for one of the summands to be equal to $c$ and the others treated as giving $0$. Give yourself a shortcut for this case when it reduces to just a bunch of circles.